# how to set selected rows in jqGrid opened from Dialog?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have created a page with a few links to open up a Dialog. There is a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Hptbb/2/

the first link is supposed to open a Dialog with ids 4 and 7 checked, the second link is supposed to open a Dialog with ids 2 and 8 checked.

It works without using the Dialog. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the code to [the following demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Hptbb/7/) which seems to work without any problems. The code of jqGrid select already the rows based on `idsOfSelectedRows` array inside of `loadComplete`. So to select new rows in the grid you need just to fill the `idsOfSelectedRows` array with new values and then call `reloadGrid`.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this fiddle, i just move all the scripts to the top.
http://jsfiddle.net/Hptbb/4/

Comment: I just want to check ids 4 and 7 checked when I click the top link. For the second link only 2 and 8.